# Laravel : Validar monto con separadores de puntos y coma para las décimas

Tags: laravel, regex, validación

Estoy tratando de validar un campo "precio", con los posibles valores, ya sea usando request o el Facade Validator.

0,25
1,25
125,00
1.250,00
1.250.000,25
1.250.000.000,25

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con PHP puro de este modo `<?php

$price = 1250000000.25;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $price) . "\n";`

Comment: Encontre algo en este web: https://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=730, es parecido con lo que estoy buscando para validar pero el problema  es que valida "1250000000.25", y tiene que validar este formato: "1.250.000.000,25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

`^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d\d)*(?:,\d{1,2})?$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XtkneX/4/)**

(Recuerda que en php debes *rodear* la expresión con algún delimitador, normalmente barras `/`. Ver [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) y [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php))

**Explicado:**

```
^                 # Inicio de línea/string
  \d{1,3}         # de 1 a 3 números
  (?:\.\d\d\d)*   # un punto y 3 números. Todo ello repetido 0 veces o más (*)
  (?:,\d{1,2})?   # una coma y de uno a dos números. Dentro de un grupo con un ?
                  # que hace que el conjunto aparezca 0 o 1 vez
$                 # Fin de línea/string
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia Julio. En este momento estoy trabajando en Laravel y te comento, coloque la validación como sugeriste y me arroja el siguiente error:

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: Aunque no soy un experto en expresiones regulares, pude arreglarlo asi: /^d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d\d)*,\d\d$/
  


Pero aun asi no me valida el campo

Comment: Si funciona, pasa que en Laravel, hay que colocar unos caracteres, quedaria asi: /^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d\d)*,\d\d$/

Comment: Ahora bien, ¿como seria si las décimas fuesen opcionales?, osea para que acepte un valor como este: 1.250

Comment: Hola @juan. Modifiqué mi respuesta para hacer los decimales opcionales. Asumo que solo quieres permitir hasta dos decimales. Si quisieras permitir cualquier cantidad, avisa y lo cambio. Efectivamente, en las funciones php preg_match y preg_replace debes pasar la expresión regular rodeada de barras. A veces se pueden utilizar otros delimitadores como `@` o `~`

Comment: Gracias @Julio, voy a poner el código de validación en Laravel, en los 2 posibles escenario, tanto con decimas obligatorio o opcional.

Answer (score 1):

Asi seria en Laravel para validar un precio ya sea con decimas obligatoria o opcional, aqui estoy utilizando un Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

       'precio_obl' => 'required|regex:/^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d\d)*,\d\d$/' //décimas obligatoria
     , 'precio_opc' => 'required|regex:/^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d\d)*(?:,\d{1,2})?$/' //décimas opcional
    ];
}
```